# matplotlib share x axis but don't show x axis tick labels for both, just one

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python + matplotlib and I'm having two plots share an axis. If you try to set `graph1.set_xticklabels([])` while sharing an axis, it has no effect because it is shared. Is there a way to share the axis AND be able to hide the x axis of one plot?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This is a common gotcha when using shared axes.

Fortunately, there's a simple fix: use [`plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp) to make the labels invisible on just one axis.

This is equivalent to `[label.set_visible(False) for label in ax.get_xticklabels()]`, for whatever it's worth.  `setp` will automatically operate on an iterable of matplotlib objects, as well as individual objects.

As an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(range(10), 'b-')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2, sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot(range(10), 'r-')

plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I had the inverse problem: The labels on the second subplot wouldn't show. so I used your command like this: ``plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=True)``. Worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 63):

Per a thread on [matplotlib-users](http://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg25311.html), you could use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for ax in plt.gcf().axes:
    try:
        ax.label_outer()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more, because it's way more helpful than the accepted answer. The only situation in which you want to modify the visibility instead of just eliminating them is on subplots; and your answer is much smarter in that case. Thanks!

Comment: Why is `try` needed? It seems fine without it.

Comment: `try` is needed because not all elements of the `plt.gcf().axes` list are guaranteed to be `subplot` instances (with a `label_outer` method).

Answer (score 39):

You could use [Axes.tick_params()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)

ax1.tick_params(labelbottom=False)
```

The `tick_params` method works also in the opposite case, when the labels are initially hidden for subplots with shared x-axis:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex="all")
ax1.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
```

Comment: Setting labelbottom=True solved it for me in the opposite case. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me too in the opposite case, while plt.setp(ax[1].get_yticklabels(), visible=True) did not.

Comment: Thank you, was struggling with it for a while

Answer (score 6):

You can share the axes during subplot creation with [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) as

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
```

This will automatically turn the ticklabels for inner axes off.

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

axes[0].plot([1,2,3])
axes[1].plot([3,2,1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: but if you try to move the ticks to the other side of the plot, the labels come back :/

Comment: Yes true, in that special case you need to set them invisible again.

Comment: `label_outer()` seems to work https://stackoverflow.com/a/12751192/125507

Comment: Yes, all answers here answer the question!?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to comment on esmit's answer (which is the best solution in my opinion, thanks esmit), so I have to write my comment as a new answer: I put his solution into a simple function

```
def remove_inner_ticklabels(fig):
    for ax in fig.axes:
        try:
            ax.label_outer()
        except:
            pass
```

which you can call before `plt.show()`. Joe Kington's answer did not work for me for some reason.