# Matlab: Don't show x-axis-labels in one of the subplots

Tags: matlab, plot, label, subplot

I want to do the same like this here: 
[matplotlib-share-x-axis-but-dont-show-x-axis-tick-labels-for-both-just-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209467/matplotlib-share-x-axis-but-dont-show-x-axis-tick-labels-for-both-just-one)

```
set(plot,'visible','off')
```

doesn't show any axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

```
set(gca,'xtick',[1 2 3 4 5], 'xticklabel',{})
```