# make only left subplots and bottom subplots (in MxN panels) contain x and y axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

Is there any way in a panel of NxM subplots to just have the axes being shown for the left column and bottom row.

```
A|N|N|N
A|N|N|N
A|N|N|N
A|A|A|A
```

Where A = axis and N = no axis

Sometimes my subplots are 10x8, 3x4, 4x9 etc. and they all have the same x and y axis. I just want it to appear on the very left and the very bottom of that subset. At the moment I have to know which axis it is plotting to and do

```
    if (figi-1) % 7 != 0:
        ax.set_yticklabels([])

    if figi < 29:
        ax1.set_xticklabels([])
```

I want to generalise this for any NxM panel arrangement without having to know before hand.
Thanks.

EDIT: I have found a way to do the y-axis. I setup the number of panels wide using:

```
nwide = 12
nhigh = 5
```

Which means I can just do

```
if (figi-1) % nwide != 0:
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
```

Any ideas for bottom?

EDIT: Worked it out. x-axis is as follows:

```
if figi < (nwide*nhigh) - nwide:
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [matplotlib share x axis but don't show x axis tick labels for both, just one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209467/matplotlib-share-x-axis-but-dont-show-x-axis-tick-labels-for-both-just-one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution is probably `pyplot.subplots()`. You can do like:

```
fig, axes = pyplot.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

[image]

and then only the left and bottom axes will have the labels displayed.

To access each subplot you can get it from `axes` like you do in a matrix: `ax = axes[i,j]`

To control the tick positions you can use:

```
ax.xaxis.set_tick_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_tick_position('left')
```

To set an axis label you can do:

```
ax.set_label_text('Something')
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the axis labels though?

Comment: you can also control the labels. For example, doing `axes[-1,-1].xaxis.set_label_text('Test')` will put a label at the bottom, right subplot...

Comment: How would I just the figure size so I don't have to drag it? Which object contains "figsize"?

Comment: @Griff `fig.set_size_inches()`

Comment: But for the axis labels, how do you only put labels on the bottom and left positions as is done with the tick marks?

Comment: you can also pass `figsize` as keyword argument to `pyplot.subplots`

Comment: for ylabels on the first column and xlabels on the last row, you can do `for a in axes[:,0]: a.set_ylabel('abc')` and `for a in axes[-1,:]: a.set_xlabel('def')`