# Remove only overlapping ticks in subplots grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a subplots grid without any spaces between the subplots, with shared x,y-axes. I only show the ticks and labels for the outer subplots. The problem is that the tick numbers overlap at the borders of the subplots. With MaxNLocator, I can remove the upper or lower ticks, but only for all plots at once.

**Question:** How can I keep the highest tick only for certain plots (in this case x=2.0 only in the bottom right subplot, and y=3 only in the top left subplot)? Why does my conditional setting of ticks for certain subplots fail?

[image]

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

numPlotsY = 3
numPlotsX = 3
f, ax_grid = plt.subplots(numPlotsY,numPlotsX,sharex=True,sharey=True)

A = np.arange(numPlotsY)+1.0
phi = np.arange(numPlotsX)
x = np.linspace(0,2.0,100)
fontsize = 18

for y_i in range(0,numPlotsY):
    for x_i in range(0,numPlotsX):
        y = A[y_i]*np.sin(x*np.pi + phi[x_i])
        ax = ax_grid[y_i,x_i]
        ax.plot(x,y,lw=2.0)

        if x_i == 0:
            ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$', fontsize=fontsize)

        if y_i == numPlotsY-1:
            ###########################
            # Why doesn't this work?! #
            ###########################
            if x_i != numPlotsX-1:
                nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
                ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
            else:
                nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
                ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune=None))
            ax.set_xlabel(r'$x/\pi$', fontsize=fontsize)

        if y_i == 0:
            ax.set_title(r'$\phi=%s$' % phi[x_i], fontsize=fontsize)

        if x_i == numPlotsX-1:
            ax.annotate(r'$A=%d$' % A[x_i], xy=(1.1,0.5), rotation=90,
                        ha='center',va='center',xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=fontsize)

f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0,hspace=0)
plt.suptitle(r'$A\cdot\sin\left(2\pi x + \phi\right)$',fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [This thread](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/sharex-with-different-tick-labels-td38913.html) says "*As the axis are shared, the ticklabels are also shared*", so what you're after might be impossible. See a closely related Q&A [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209467/matplotlib-share-x-axis-but-dont-show-x-axis-tick-labels-for-both-just-one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AndrasDeak pointed out, I cannot modify individual subplot ticks as long as I have set sharex=True,sharey=True. **The solution is to set them to false**

```
f, ax_grid = plt.subplots(numPlotsY,numPlotsX,sharex=False,sharey=False)
```

**and changing the conditional statements from my original post to:**

```
# If left-most column:  Remove all overlapping y-ticks
# Else:                 Remove all ticks
if x_i == 0:
    ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$', fontsize=fontsize)
    # If top left subplot:      Remove bottom y-tick
    # If bottom left subplot:   Remove top y-tick
    # Else:                     Remove top and bottom y-ticks
    if y_i == 0:
        nbins = len(ax.get_yticklabels())
        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='lower'))
    elif y_i == numPlotsY-1:
        nbins = len(ax.get_yticklabels())
        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
    else:
        nbins = len(ax.get_yticklabels())
        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='both'))
else:
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])

# If bottom row:    Remove all overlapping x-ticks
# Else:             Remove all ticks
if y_i == numPlotsY-1:
    # If bottom left subplot:   Remove right x-tick
    # If bottom right subplot:  Remove top left x-tick
    # Else:                     Remove left and right x-ticks
    if x_i == 0:
        nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
    elif x_i == numPlotsX-1:
        nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='lower'))
    else:
        nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='both'))
else:
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
```

Not the most elegant result, but it demonstrates how to manipulate only the overlapping ticks:
[image]

Full code for anyone interested:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

numPlotsY = 3
numPlotsX = 3
f, ax_grid = plt.subplots(numPlotsY,numPlotsX,sharex=False,sharey=False)

A = np.arange(numPlotsY)+1.0
phi = np.arange(numPlotsX)
x = np.linspace(0,2.0,100)
fontsize = 18

for y_i in range(0,numPlotsY):
    for x_i in range(0,numPlotsX):
        y = A[y_i]*np.sin(x*np.pi + phi[x_i])
        ax = ax_grid[y_i,x_i]
        ax.plot(x,y,lw=2.0)

        # If left-most column:  Remove all overlapping y-ticks
        # Else:                 Remove all ticks
        if x_i == 0:
            ax.set_ylabel(r'$y$', fontsize=fontsize)
            # If top left subplot:      Remove bottom y-tick
            # If bottom left subplot:   Remove top y-tick
            # Else:                     Remove top and bottom y-ticks
            if y_i == 0:
                nbins = len(ax.get_yticklabels())
                ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='lower'))
            elif y_i == numPlotsY-1:
                nbins = len(ax.get_yticklabels())
                ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
            else:
                nbins = len(ax.get_yticklabels())
                ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='both'))
        else:
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])

        # If bottom row:    Remove all overlapping x-ticks
        # Else:             Remove all ticks
        if y_i == numPlotsY-1:
            # If bottom left subplot:   Remove right x-tick
            # If bottom right subplot:  Remove top left x-tick
            # Else:                     Remove left and right x-ticks
            if x_i == 0:
                nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
                ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='upper'))
            elif x_i == numPlotsX-1:
                nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
                ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='lower'))
            else:
                nbins = len(ax.get_xticklabels())
                ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=nbins,prune='both'))
        else:
            ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])

        if y_i == 0:
            ax.set_title(r'$\phi=%s$' % phi[x_i], fontsize=fontsize)

        if x_i == numPlotsX-1:
            ax.annotate(r'$A=%d$' % A[x_i], xy=(1.1,0.5), rotation=90,
                        ha='center',va='center',xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=fontsize)

f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0,hspace=0)
plt.suptitle(r'$A\cdot\sin\left(2\pi x + \phi\right)$',fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Might be a silly question, but why get rid of all the ticks, when what you really want is get rid of the ticklabels? I mean, except the outer ones, simply set the formatter to the nullformatter, no?

Comment: @BUFU good point. It is mainly the tick labels that I want(ed) to get rid off. The ticks can definitely remain.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by fromGiants's answer, I got a cleaner solution. I use `plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels()[0], visible=False)` to set yticklabels invisible.

```py
def clear_overlapped_ticks(axs, axis='xy'):
    ny = len(axs)
    nx = len(axs[0])
    for y_i in range(0, ny):
        for x_i in range(0, nx):
            ax = axs[y_i][x_i]
            if 'y' in axis:
                if x_i == 0:
                    # If not bottom left subplot:   Remove bottom y-tick
                    if y_i < ny - 1:
                        print("here's the current ylabels:", ax.get_yticklabels())
                        plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels()[0], visible=False)
                else:
                    ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
                    ax.set_ylabel('')
            if 'x' in axis:
                if y_i == ny - 1:
                    # If not bottom left subplot:   Remove left x-tick
                    if x_i > 0:
                        print("here's the current xlabels:",
                              [i for i in ax.get_xticklabels()])
                        plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels()[0], visible=False)
                else:
                    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
                    ax.set_xlabel('')
```